# Making an npm script auto start in a FreeBSD Jail

Tags: node.js, shell, freebsd, rc, jail

I've installed an npm package / script in a JAIL on FreeNAS 9.10. (FreeBSD based)
It works perfectly if I run "npm start" in the directory where the scripts are installed.

However, I need this to be auto-starting when the jail starts. I don't know now to do that. Do I need to create an rc script?

Basically all I need to do is give the "npm start" in the correct directory on start up. How do I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can place an rc script within the jail and enable it using the jail's `/etc/rc.conf` file.

But, for a quick and dirty solution, you could create a `/etc/rc.local` script (also within the jail's environment) and put your startup commands in there.

See the [manual page here](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.local).

Comment: Don't think that works with npm commands unfortunately; it doesn't daemonise

Comment: I can't work out a way to daemonise a node script on FreeNAS/FreeBSD none of the forever type solutions seem to work on FreeBSD

Comment: Ok, it worked like this using /etc/rc.local: "/usr/local/bin/node path/to/server.js"

Answer (score 4):

Don't know about npm start, but for node.js I made such RC srcipt:

```
#!/bin/sh

# $FreeBSD: 340872 2014-01-24 00:14:07Z mat $
#
# PROVIDE: SERVICENAME
# REQUIRE: NETWORKING
# KEYWORD: shutdown
#
# Add the following line to /etc/rc.conf to enable SERVICENAME:
#
# SERVICENAME_enable="YES"
#

. /etc/rc.subr

name="SERVICENAME"
rcvar=SERVICENAME_enable
pidfile=${SERVICENAME_pidfile:-"/var/run/SERVICENAME.pid"}
command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
#command_args="-r -u USERNAME -P /var/run/SERVICENAME.pid /usr/local/bin/node /home/USERNAME/PROGDIR" # cjayho: restart if crashed
command_args="-u USERNAME -P /var/run/SERVICENAME.pid /usr/local/bin/node /home/USERNAME/PROGDIR"

load_rc_config $name
: ${SERVICENAME_enable:="NO"}

run_rc_command "$1"
```

name this file something like **SERVICENAME** and put to **/usr/local/etc/rc.d**

to enable automatic startup run command as root:

```
sysrc SERVICENAME_enable="YES"
```

do not forget to replace **SERVICENAME**, **USERNAME** and **PROGDIR** to your values, and add

```
process.chdir('/home/USERNAME/PROGDIR')
```

to your entry js file.